# How to upload image with other data into the google drive app specific folder and get back into the app in json formate in Swift

Tags: arrays, json, swift, image, google-drive-api

I have successfully integration the google drive sync by using [this link has the source code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56867026/how-to-access-app-specific-folder-and-use-it-to-backup-or-some-app-specific-data)
And now I am not able to upload image with its name id and location, 
I want to upload image with some other fields like name, height, width into the app specific private folder, 
If this is not possible can any one suggest me how to go with this:
Actually I have to sync application list data in which list contains images, title, comments ratings and so forth. I am able to upload all other fields except images in json formate, any suggestion upload some type of approach to get this

Answer (score 0):

**Found the solution**

It is not proper solution but till I am not getting the exact solution, perfect for me.

To upload image with other request data, I have followed following steps:

1. Convert the image into data using one of the following way

**Swift 4**

```
let dataObj = image.pngData()
```

**Swift 3**

```
let dataObj = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)
```

2. And convert this data objet to string with utf8

   ```
   let str = String(decoding: data, as: UTF8.self)
   ```

Use this string to upload with other requst param or data.

And don't forgot to mention the type with this, so that you can easily convert this string to data again and from data, image easily can convert.